# Binomial Distribution word problem (basketball)

Tags: probability

I made this problem up:
Lebron James has a free throw percentage of 0.71 if he shoots 100 shots from the free throw line, what is the probability he will make 70 of those shots?. 
I used the binomial distribution and found it to be around 9%. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe the probability of 70 successes in a Binomial with $p=0.71$ is

$$(100C70) (0.71)^{70}(0.29)^{30} $$ (where $100C70$ means "100 choose 70") Or you can use normal approximations to the binomial.

EDIT: As DonkeyKong pointed out, it seems a god idea to make explicit that the trials ( free shots) are independent and " identically distributed", i.e., $p=0.71$ for each shot. In that case, one may use the computation above.

Comment: He cannot justify using a Binomial with $p = 0.71$ given how his question is worded.

Comment: I understand, but this to be a natural assumption to make, given s/he is referring to a binomial distribution problem.

Comment: But given that they wrote the problem themselves, I think that it is probably extremely important for them to understand that the Binomial distribution is not actually applicable given how they wrote it. With the wording of the question, using the Binomial distribution is an incorrect assumption to make.

Comment: OK, you have a point; it is difficult to know what the OP is assuming and whether they are aware of this assumption and, for the sake of others who may read the answer, it seems better to make this assumption explicit.

Comment: Honestly after reading the question again, a binomial distribution could be suitable if he added a comma :P but it is poorly written as it stands.

Comment: @DonkeyKong: I agree, please see my edit.